# What does "fa proprio un gran sangue" mean?

Tags: word-usage, meaning

In the following quote from the film "Radiofreccia" the expression 'fare sangue' or 'fare un gran sangue' is used in referring to a character's mother. Here is the quote:

> Sei stato sempre becco papà. Lo sapevano tutti, e secondo me lo sapevi anche te. Però io ti capisco, perché… sì, insomma… io non ne so niente di Freud, non Freud: però la mamma ***fa proprio un gran sangue***. Insomma io lo capisco che per una così si può perdere la testa, il problema però è che non si può avere l’esclusiva su di una come lei.

Despite looking for the expression in dictionaries, I am having trouble finding a definitive meaning for the expression in this context.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer to your question, please consider the option to "accept" it by clicking a checkmark next to the answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- The meaning has a sexual nuance. The author is saying that his mother is "sexy" and that fact  in part explains why she has been an unfaithful wife.
- I think it is a regional idiomatic expression and the idea is of blood going to your head because of strong emotions. So "far sangue" literally "make blood" refers to her sensuality that arouses strong emotions in those who look at her.
- You can find similar definitions [here](https://it.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110323065235AAbhG2Q).
- A more common  and widely understood expression with a similar meaning is "fare sesso" as in " lei mi fa un gran sesso".

Comment: Correct, it's regional: In my experience I have heard it used "natively" (i.e. not because they heard it and liked it) only from peoples from Abruzzo and Emilia Romagna. Probably it's more diffuse, but I don't think it's used in the northern regions at all. It's also very evocative: think of the (kinda) equivalent English "blood rush"

Comment: @DiegoMartinoia Thanks. That makes sense considering the movie is set in Emilia Romagna.